# How to display chart's colors in amchart?

Tags: amcharts

I want to test amcharts,so I tried this demo [amcharts demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-time-line-pie-chart/) to have more idea. But when I ran it in jsfiddle, the color of the chart is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color works fine for me in jsfiddle. I tested this in Firefox, IE 11, Chrome and Edge. If you're running in a small resolution, you might need to expand the output frame in jsfiddle so that the chart has enough room to display the slices. I noticed this when accessing jsfiddle on a laptop with a 1366x768 resolution.